# By swap valuation, is accrued interest calculated?

Tags: fixed-income, swaps, interest-rate-swap

If I treat the 2 legs as bonds, and I want to calculate the present value somewhere between 2 payment date, should I calculate accrued interest?

Answer (score 1):

When you sum up all the discounted cash flows, you effectively a "dirty price" (i.e., inclusive of "accrued interest"). This quantity is used for marking to market or unwinding. You don't need to worry about "accrued interest" separately.

Comment: Does that mean in a swap, the accrual interest for both legs are cancelled?

Comment: @StudentT They won't cancel out completely, since the flt/fixed rates, day count conventions, payment frequency are all different.

Comment: Could you give an explicit formula? As far as I can see, the price at time $T_0 < t < T_1$ should be the sum of prices of a forward starting swap (i.e. the swap with the first resent date $T_1 > t$) and $P(t,T_1)\tau(T_0, t)(L(T_0, T_1) - K)$ where this last term is the PV of the accrued interest since the last resent date $T_0$ to be paid at time $T_1$.